# How to box select only included Faces in Blender 2.8 c13e10a7404d

Tags: selection-tools

How do I box select only fully included faces in newest Blender?
It seems the button for it was removed?

[image]

**EDIT:**
Even after understanding that box select now has two modes depending on if one fully encapsulates something the behaviour for me still is undeterministic.

I fully enclose a lot of faces - still the top triangle that is not fully enclosed gets selected

[image]

[image]

I'd love to attach the .blend but https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ does not seem to work right now.

**EDIT2:**
It seems pretty undeterministic:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112307/can-3dview-border-select-behavior-be-changed/

Comment: Ah thank you very much. I searched but didnt find that Question.

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119472/blender-2-8-how-to-select-edges-behind-other-edges-when-in-numpad-1-mode/

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos If you have the time and leisure I´ve updated my question with edits :)

Comment: You seem to be in edge selection mode rather than face

Comment: Nope definitely in face mode. (but wireframe view for better display)

Comment: And even if I were in edge (which im not) it would be undeterministic.

Comment: Which of the five modes , N panel tools category, are you using?  "Set a new selection" being default.

Comment: @batFINGER took me some secs to find but yes "Set a new selection" is set :)